# Error! Cannot find Class error with ant 1.10.8 Java 8 and XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant

i have legacy code running on Ant 1.6 and Java 1.4 and now i am upgrading to Ant 1.10.8 and Java 8. it uses XSLT to transform files.
but when i run deploy the app with upgraded versions, deployment fails because it is not able to load a class which is present in classpath.
below is the ant target

```
<target name="generate">
<property file="/etc/adminkey"/>
<xslt processor="trax" force="true" in="prop.xml" style="xslt/prop.xslt" out="logger.properties">
  <param name="envname" expression="${env.ENV_NAME}"/>
  <param name="packagename" expression="logger"/>
  <param name="rootdir"   expression="${env.ROOT_DIR}"/>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/bin/util.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</xslt>
</target>
```

and prop.xslt i am using a Class from util.jar

i suspect that somehow classpath is getting ignored. but can't figure out why.

below is the stacktrace.

```
generate:
INFO -      [echo] Generating logger.properties file...
INFO -      [xslt] Processing prop.xml to logger.properties
INFO -      [xslt] Loading stylesheet xslt/prop.xslt
INFO -      [xslt] : Error! Cannot find class 'com.group.tools.util.Encrypter'.
INFO -      [xslt] : Error! Cannot find external method 'com.group.tools.util.Encrypter.decryptwithkey' (must be public).
INFO -      [xslt] : Fatal Error! Cannot find external method 'com.group.tools.util.Encrypter.decryptwithkey' (must be public).
INFO -      [xslt] Failed to process prop.xml
ERROR - 
ERROR - BUILD FAILED
ERROR - prop.xml:10: Fatal error during transformation using xslt/props.xslt: Cannot find external method 'com.group.tools.util.Encrypter.decryptwithkey' (must be public).
ERROR - 
ERROR - Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: Can you add the specific error stacktrace?

Comment: @AlbertoSegura added.

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of Ant and the JDK, loading of extension functions is disabled by default, for security reasons. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html section "Note on XSLT extension functions".

Comment: according to the "Note on XSLT extension functions" it should work if i disable FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING flag in TransformerFactory. so i did disable both Security Manager and FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING flag. but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem, it was happening because the path to jar in xslt was wrong, it was working with older version because the jar was available in ant lib directory.